# Call a number ‘funky’ if it has some multiple in which every digit is a 1.Which natural numbers are funky?

Tags: number-theory

So $37$ is funky because $37  \mid  111$ and $7$ is funky as $7  \mid  111111$
How can I consider $(10^{\phi(9n)} -1)/9$ in this and solve?

Comment: In base $10,$ all $n,(n,10)=1$ are

Comment: @N.S.JOHN, Are these two statement different?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I stand corrected

Comment: Not an even number obviously.